# Is it possible to create an Access runtime using MySQL tables to distribute to other people?

Tags: mysql, ms-access, backend

I am rather new at distributing databases and am unsure if this is possible without having to include MySQL drivers or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

I have to say it's one of the oddest combinations I've heard of.

Windows does not include MySQL connectivity.  Therefore you would have to ship and install MySQL drivers with your application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the question is, as the way you've worded it makes it seem like you understand the issues.

1. yes, you could create an Access runtime install that doesn't include the MySQL support, on the assumption that it's already installed.
2. I haven't used the recent runtime distribution tools, but the old ones used to allow you to chain installers, or include components from outside the runtime for installation. However, I didn't use ODBC back then, so don't know what the issues are for that.
3. you could use something like the Inno installer to have a single package that installs your runtime and your MyODBC drivers.

If you've tried any of these and run into problems, perhaps you should edit your question to incorporate that information, since that will help people provide better answers.

Answer (score 0):

In my previous workplace there were an old application using MS Access VBA and MySQL. We used to distribute it with MySQL ODBC Connector, and storing the configuration in a local MS Access table.

At first the app relies on DSN ODBC to store the login information, but then we moved to what i mentioned above.

I tried to convince my boss to move the app to the .NET Framework but i didn't succeed because he loves VBA.